# Does iPhone use USB tethering to share internet when connected to Macbook?

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, usb, tethering

I am currently confused if the iPhone does support sharing internet via USB cable or not. I was able to share my mobile data from iPhone to Macbook via USB cable, still need to enable Personal Hotspot Wi-Fi in Macbook is turn off. However I have a scenario where I am trying to connect to someone's Wi-Fi, the connection in Macbook is having trouble with Wi-Fi icon having exclamation saying the laptop is connected to network but cannot reached internet.

My iPhone can successfully connect to this network so I tried to use the same approach from the above, sharing internet coming from iPhone's Wi-Fi to Macbook via USB cable but unsuccessful.

Comment: If you’re asking a yes no question, yes iPhone tethering (and iPad tethering) provide network hotspot / routing over Bluetooth, USB (lightning and USB-C) as well as WiFi. My guess is you’re asking how to troubleshoot that when it doesn’t just work, though. Can you clarify your problem with an edit?

Comment: @bmike does it also work when iPhone is connected to Wi-Fi and share it to Macbook via USB cable?

Comment: No - hotspot is to send cellular data out. Not extend a WiFi network to wired. When hotspot is enabled on iPadOS and iOS it disconnects from whatever WiFi was associated and broadcasts a base station signal for others to join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, personal hotspot doesn’t let you connect to WiFi and then share that network over USB or Bluetooth. All three networks (phone WiFi, USB, Bluetooth) connect through your phone to a cellular network only.

Yes, personal hotspot shares networking over USB cable to other devices.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204023

If you run into issues, here are some great steps to follow before getting extra help from Apple or here.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203302